# Is Sabre Central / Tulsa time zone a subject of daylight saving?

Tags: sabre

[Official Sabre docs](https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/PassengerNameRecordPNR/OverviewPassengerNameRecordPNR/DateandTimesStampsinPNROnline.aspx?ItemID=78350f0205bb4cf592c533c2c7a1d7a0) states that PNRs creation, history and fare date/time in:

> Reflects Tulsa time (Always in Central Time - CT).

Is it `America/Chicago` IANA TZ (so `ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")` for Java)?

Is it subject of daylight saving (so UTC-05 in summer and UTC-06 in winter)? That means ambiguity at 1AM when time goes back one night in autumn (from 2AM to 1 AM)...

Comment: Your link does not go directly to the specific documentation.

Comment: If you are merely asking about time zones, this would be off-topic for this site. If you are asking a programming question, edit to be more clear and explicit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.